# Is gezeirah shavah limited to specific contexts?

Tags: hermeneutics, gezeira-shava

My understanding of gezeirah shavah (GS) was that it

1. must come from tradition (one cannot invent one's own)
2. involves identical unnecessary words in (at least) two different contexts
3. *does not have to involve other appearances of this word elsewhere*

Apparently I was wrong:

The repeated argument on [Shabbat 132a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.132a.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) goes like this:

- There is a GS of word W in contexts 1 & 2 which proves something about 2 from 1

This is refuted like this:

- But word W also appears in context 3 to which the derivation from 1 does not apply.

This seems to imply that GS of a word **must** apply to ***ALL*** appearances
of that word (which does not seem to be the case - we have seen many
GS on relatively common words and this argument - that the GS must
then apply to all "free" appearances of the word - never surfaced).

What am I missing?

Comment: They may have had a tradition that it applied in all three contexts, in which case that would make this argument one that couldn’t be made in other places.

Comment: Just found another example of this in Yevamos 17b. Also Tosafos in Pesachim 32b asks it on a gemarra as well. So that's a case where the gemarra didn't do this, when it could have

Answer (score 3):

The *sefer* [**Halichos Olam** 4:16](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=16918&pagenum=149) by the 15th century *Rishon* [**Rav Yeshua ben Yosef HaLevi**](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/jeshua-ben-joseph-ha-levi), coming from the [**Ramban**](https://www.sefaria.org/Hasagot_HaRamban_on_Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Shorashim.2.3?vhe=Sefer_HaMitzvot,_Warsaw_1883&lang=he), says that there are two types of *gezeiros shavos*. One is that *Chazal* accepted that two *parshiyos* are to be learned one from the other, but they weren't sure which words connected the two. One example is the *parsha* of *ones* (a rapist) and *mefateh* (a seducer). The two share similar laws and are learned one from the other. Nevertheless, the *gemarra* has a dispute about which words connect the two.

Another type of *gezeira shava* is when *Chazal* had accepted that a certain word is to be used for a *gezeira shava*, but they don't know where to apply it. I believe your *gemarra* is an example. The *gemarra* is suggesting that the *gezeira shava* is this particular word (אות, דורות, etc.). However, *Chazal* didn't know where to apply it. The *gemarra* is suggesting to apply it in contexts 1 & 2  (like you say), but that's not definitive. If we are to employ such a *gezeira shava*, perhaps it should be 1 & 3.

In the case of that *gemarra* for example, it's suggesting to learn *Bris Milah* overrides Shabbos because of a *gezeira shava* of אות אות. However, if you were to learn that *gezeira shava* teaches you that something overrides Shabbos, the *gemarra* is saying that  perhaps the *gezeira shava* is to apply between Shabbos and Tefillin, which also has such a word. Since we know (from elsewhere) that Tefillin doesn't override Shabbos, the *gemarra* rejects using that *gezeira shava*.

I'm not sure if the *gemarra* is saying to apply it in this context **instead**, or **additionally**. Either way, the **Halichos Olam** and **Ramban** are limiting how much *Chazal* really accepted from tradition. The rest was up to them to figure out, where the *gemarra* you're quoting shows the back and forth.

Why the *gemarra* doesn't always ask this, I'm not sure. Perhaps finding a case where this happens would make it clear why it didn't.

Comment: This is all very interesting, but the only part of your answer relevant to my question is, alas, your last paragraph.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, I addressed your first premise and noted it's not as broad as you put it, and explained the shaklya vetarya in the gemarra differently than you understood it. According to my explanation, the gemarra makes sense with the rules of gezeira shava. I thought that was your question. You rejected the possibility that a gezeira shava needs to work for all instances of a word, as we see that's not true. I admit I don't know why the gemarra doesn't always have a shakla vetarya like the one in Shabbos, but it doesn't negate the validity of my answer.

Comment: Could you please provide an example where the gemarra doesn't do this, and show what the gemarra should have asked?

Comment: Bottom line: Are you asking why the gemarra doesn't always ask this? Or are you asking how the gemarra could ask this according to the rules of gezeira shava. I answered #2.

Comment: My question is, indeed, why aren't _all_ GS refuted based on the appearance of the word in an inapplicable context?

Comment: As for your (very interesting indeed, thanks!) answer -- why can't the 1st party just answer: my GC is not applicable to context 3, so your "refutation" is dead. Unless, of course, what you are saying is that the 1st party is unsure about that... But even if they are unsure, they could just say that okay, so the GS is only applicable to contexts 1&2, but not 3. I mean, _how come context 3 can even enter the conversation_?